# Standard 8 Puzzle Depth First Search

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph

I'm working on the standard 8 puzzle solver, and have successfully gotten it to work with BFS. Depth first, on the other hand, infinitely loops. Here's my code for the DFS algoritm:

```
    public static void depthFirstSolver(PuzzleNode initialNode)
{
    Stack<PuzzleNode> puzzleStack = new Stack<PuzzleNode>();
    puzzleStack.push(initialNode);
    HashSet<PuzzleNode> visitedPuzzles = new HashSet<PuzzleNode>();
    int[][] goalState = initialNode.getGoalState();

    for(PuzzleNode pn : initialNode.childrenPuzzles)
    {
        pn.generateChildren();
        puzzleStack.push(pn);
    }

    while(!puzzleStack.isEmpty())
    {
        PuzzleNode temp = puzzleStack.pop();
        temp.generateChildren();
        LinkedList<PuzzleNode> childrenPuzzles = temp.childrenPuzzles;

        if(Arrays.deepEquals(temp.getPuzzleState(), goalState))
        {
            System.out.println("CURRENT STATE: ");
            temp.printPuzzleState();
            temp.findCompletePathFromRoot();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!visitedPuzzles.contains(temp))
            {
                for(PuzzleNode pn : childrenPuzzles)
                {
                    pn.generateChildren();
                    puzzleStack.push(pn);
                }

                temp.setPuzzleNodeVisited();
                temp.printPuzzleState();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the generateChildren method:

```
    public void generateChildren()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        PuzzleNode temp = new PuzzleNode(puzzleState, this);
        if(temp.moveBlank(i) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("I:" + i); //diag
            childrenPuzzles.add(temp);
            temp.printPuzzleState(); //diag
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is moveBlank:

```
    public boolean moveBlank(int whichDirectionToMove)
{
    //0 = left, 1 = right, 2 = up, 3 = down
    boolean[] placesToMove = getMovableBlankPositions();

    if(placesToMove[whichDirectionToMove] == false)
        return false;

    //DIAG
    System.out.println("************************************");
    //DIAG

    switch(whichDirectionToMove)
    {
        case 0: //left
        {
            int temp = puzzleState[blankRow][blankCol - 1];
            puzzleState[blankRow][blankCol - 1] = 0;
            puzzleState[blankRow][blankCol] = temp;
            blankCol--;
            movementType = "move blank left";
            // DIAG
             System.out.println("moved blank left");
            // DIAG
            break;
        }
        case 1: //right
        {
            int temp = puzzleState[blankRow][blankCol + 1];
            puzzleState[blankRow][blankCol + 1] = 0;
            puzzleState[blankRow][blankCol] = temp;
            blankCol++;
            movementType = "move blank right";
            // DIAG
             System.out.println("moved blank right");
            // DIAG
            break;
        }
        case 2: //up
        {
            int temp = puzzleState[blankRow - 1][blankCol];
            puzzleState[blankRow - 1][blankCol] = 0;
            puzzleState[blankRow][blankCol] = temp;
            blankRow--;
            movementType = "move blank up";
            // DIAG
             System.out.println("moved blank up");
            // DIAG
            break;
        }
        case 3: //down
        {
            int temp = puzzleState[blankRow + 1][blankCol];
            puzzleState[blankRow + 1][blankCol] = 0;
            puzzleState[blankRow][blankCol] = temp;
            blankRow++;
            movementType = "move blank down";
            // DIAG
             System.out.println("moved blank down");
            // DIAG
            break;
        }   
    }       
    return true;    
}
```

In essence, move blank is given a value 0-3, where: 0 = left, 1 = right, 2 = up, 3 = down. The PuzzleNode class contains a linkedlist of potential moves. This list is called childrenPuzzles, and is updated when the generateChildren() method is called. getMovableBlankPositions() returns a 4 index bool array, whose indicies (and t/f value), determine if the space in these directions can be used. BFS works great, it's DFS that infinitely loops. Any suggestions?

Comment: Depth first search has to be guaranteed to stop eventually along each branch. The 8-puzzle has potentially unlimited depth, so unless you stop DFS early or get lucky you're just going to go forever. Why do you want to use DFS?

Comment: For an assignment. I tried a recursive solution, although there was a stack overflow

Comment: It seems like an inappropriate use of DFS. Closest thing that might work is Monte Carlo Tree Search. Perhaps if you knew the maximum number of moves needed to get to a solved state you could cut off after that many moves. Recursive solution overflows stack for the same reason this loops infinitely. I'd ask your professor.

Comment: I should add that the puzzles are all solvable. I take a goal state (0-8), and rearrange it several times, then attempt to use DFS

Answer (score 0):

Here the main problem is that u are using same puzzleState array to make the child nodes which is wrong way to do it because the same reference is modified everytime you create a child and all child will have the same puzzleState at the end.

**Note:-** To get around it u must use new puzzleState array to create children.

Comment: This is not the case. My constructor manually clones the puzzleState element by element into a new int[][], preventing this

Comment: @bensherms what are is equals function in the PuzzleNode as it is important to get your hashset working correctly